# Views archive page showing year and months of article content type

Tags: views

I am trying to build a view page that shows archives (content type is article) only by dates:

year (e.g.2016)
february (post count)
june (post count)
etc ..

year (e.g. 2017)
march (post count)
june (post count)

To top it off, months being linked to the respective posts.

i tried with contextual filters using content: created year and content: created month but I only end up with the year.

Using Drupal 8.3.3.

I am not sure if my set up is missing something because when using fields and/or contextual filters I do not have a date option ...

Any kind soul who can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [calendar module](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar), from module page:

> This module will display any Views date field in calendar formats, including CCK date fields, node created or updated dates, etc. Switch between year, month, and day views. Back and next navigation is provided for all views. Lots of the Calendar functionality comes from the Date module, so any time you update the Calendar module you should be sure you also update to the latest version of the Date module at the same time.

this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Tr1sZBFRWU) is for D7, for D8 is very similar, you can change display format in any view, for example a table and add a special field that you can find ir in views UI under "global" named "views reasult counter"

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am not sure if I understand ... To output a list with a year and subdivided in months I need a date/calendar module?

Comment: no, you could do it by filters (exposed, not exposed and contextual), and it will be complicataded, with calendar module it will work out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, I looked into the module and the video but since I am on drupal 8.3.3 the module at the moment seems a bit buggy so I am looking to get the result by just setting up the view.